# Question on Python Feature Selection (null values)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data

I'm building a logistic regression model, and want to understand the features that contribute the most to my output (1 or 0). Trying to understand if a customer comes back to my website, what features are making them come back. I am getting stuck with this fit function. It errors out on me and I can't figure out why. It seems to indicate that I have some null values, but I've scrubbed through my data and removed the null values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

#load data
df = pd.read_csv('jupyter.csv', header = 0)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,1:13]
Y = array[:,14]
print (X.shape)
print (Y.shape)
(544219, 12)
(544219,)

# feature extraction
test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=4)
fit = test.fit(X, Y)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-f91db4d08897> in <module>
      1 # feature extraction
      2 test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=4)
----> 3 fit = test.fit(X, Y)
      4 # summarize scores
      5 #numpy.set_printoptions(precision=3)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py in fit(self, X, y)
    339         self : object
    340         """
--> 341         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc'], multi_output=True)
    342 
    343         if not callable(self.score_func):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,
--> 722                         dtype=None)
    723     else:
    724         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 542                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    543 
    544     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     58     elif X.dtype == np.dtype('object') and not allow_nan:
     59         if _object_dtype_isnan(X).any():
---> 60             raise ValueError("Input contains NaN")
     61 
     62 
ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

Comment: Before fitting, try `X = X.reset_index()` and  `Y = Y.reset_index()`

Comment: So `df.iloc[:, :14].isnull().sum().sum()` returns 0? If not I suggest you look at `df[df.iloc[:, :14].isnull().any(1)]`

Comment: Yes @ALollz. It returns 0.

Comment: So just noticed that `array = dataframe.values` seems to be using some variable **dataframe** which is **not** the `df` you read in the previous line?

Comment: Thanks you ALollz! Yes, that was a mistake on my part.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *impute* missing values using:

- [`SimpleImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#impute), or
- using pandas [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). For example, the following code will impute all missing values with the *mean*:

```
X.fillna(X.mean())
```